# Scaling for non-negative sparse data in R

Tags: r, scale, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix (30% of observations values are 0).

How I can do centring and scaling to have all values between 0 and 1 (scale function gives negative values for the sparse cell).

The result will be an input of a convolutional neural network

Comment: This might be a better question for cross validated.

Comment: The question is unanswered on croos validated since three years. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153832/feature-scaling-for-non-negative-sparse-data

Comment: Would a uniform(0, 1) distribution do?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will transform your non zero matrix entries in a random variable that follows a standard uniform distribution by applying the `ecdf` of the data.

```
set.seed(1234)    # Make the results reproducible
n <- 1e2
mat <- matrix(rnorm(n*n, sd = 10), nrow = n)
mat[sample(0.3*n*n)] <- 0
mean(mat == 0)
#[1] 0.3

f <- ecdf(mat[mat != 0])
mat[mat != 0] <- f(mat[mat != 0])

mean(mat[mat != 0])  # should be 0.5
#[1] 0.5000714

sd(mat[mat != 0])    # should be sqrt(1/12)
#[1] 0.2886958

sqrt(1/12)
#[1] 0.2886751
```